# Which is better way to get exception message: str(e) vs e.args[0]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Let's consider a case where I throw built-in `Exception` **with message** and when handling it I store exception message. I know I can do it in 2 ways like in an example below.

```py
try:
    raise Exception('some message')
except Exception as e:
    value_str = str(e)
    value_args = e.args[0]
```

**Is there any rationale that one way is better than the other?**

Comment: args is already initialised then there is no issue but if it is not initialised then it throws a index error. But this is not the case  with value_str.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, using `str(e)` would be safer because there are cases where `e.args[0]` can raise an index error:

```py
try:
    raise Exception()
except Exception as e:
    value = e.args[0]

>>> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

There are also cases where the first argument is not actually the message whereas `str(e)` simply calls `e.__str__()` which should always return the message.

However, in your specific case using `e.args[0]` seems to be slightly faster:

```py
import timeit


def test_args():
    try:
        raise Exception('some message')
    except Exception as e:
        value = e.args[0]


def test_str():
    try:
        raise Exception('some message')
    except Exception as e:
        value = str(e)


print(timeit.timeit('test_args()', setup='from __main__ import test_args'))
print(timeit.timeit('test_str()', setup='from __main__ import test_str'))

>>> 0.5408027
>>> 0.5728966000000001
```

If this minimal increase in execution speed matters and you are certain that `e` always has at least one argument, go for `e.args[0]`. When catching specific types of exceptions, you could also consider directly accessing attributes. In all other cases I recommend using `str(e)`.

See the [`traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html) for more options of retrieving information from your exceptions.

Comment: I'm asking about this one specific case. Where I'm sure there is argument passed to exception and I retrieve it beeing aware of it. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Because of the way you formulated your question, I was considering a more general scenario. I edited my answer to also include your specific case. Let me know if you still need more info.

Comment: The performance consideration is so minimal as to be irrelevant. I'd consider accessing attributes of custom exception classes directly, but for any 3rd party/builtin exception there's simply no API guarantee to rely on, so `str` looks like the only safe and sane option.

Comment: As noone seems to have anything else to add to this question and I use Exception in controlled way I'll go with `e.args[0]`. There is no documentation that states any arguments against this solution and small performance increase seems to be valid advantage in this case. Thx @Jonathan and @deceze for contributing.